# Неправильно распознаёт .py файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pyqt5

Доброго времени суток.

В linux 20.2(uma), в файловом менеджере - Nemo

Работая с python файлом(linux.py), неправиольно распознает файл хотя расширение - .py, но распозает он его как qml,
до изменения этой строчки все валидно:

```
self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #22222e")
```

[image: Все работает верно]

после замены её на эту строчку файловый файловый менеджер
начинает опознавать файл как qml(Qt Murkup Language),:

```
    self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("QTabBar::tab:selected  {\n"
"    background-color:rgb(121, 193, 162);\n"
"    color: white;\n"
"}  \n"
"QTabBar::tab:!selected {\n"
"    background-color:rgb(34, 34, 46);\n"
"    color: white; \n"
"}\n" 
"")
```

[image: здесь Nemo неправильно определяет тип файла]

хоть код и был написан с использованием библиотеки pyqt5,
но расширение было поставлено .py, но файловый менеджер начинает додумывать.

Все работает корректно и никаких ошибок в самом приложении не присутствует. Но файловый менеджер очень сильно раздражает тем что не понимает что это .py файл.

Можно ли как нибудь сделать так чтобы тип выбирался по расширению а не так как он делает это сейчас?

так же пытался задать программу для исполнения по умолчанию на /usr/bin/python3 - не помогло.

Заранее спасибо :D

Полный код задания интерфейса приложению:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QClipboard
import os
import string
from random import randint, choice
import sys
from datetime import datetime as dt

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.main_path = os.getcwd()
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(os.path.join(os.getcwd() + "/log/lock.ico")))
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setFixedSize(750, 650)
        MainWindow.setStyle(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create("oxygen"))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("URW Gothic L")
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(34, 34, 46)")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 750, 650))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("URW Gothic [UKWN]")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.tabWidget.setFont(font)
        self.tabWidget.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.tabWidget.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("QTabBar::tab:selected{background-color:rgb(121, 193, 162);color: white;}QTabBar::tab:!selected{background-color:rgb(34, 34, 46);color: white;}")
        self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(False)
        self.tabWidget.setMovable(True)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab_check = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_check.setStyleSheet("")
        self.tab_check.setObjectName("tab_check")
        self.frame_main = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.tab_check)
        self.frame_main.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-5, 0, 760, 150))
        self.frame_main.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(125, 200, 167, 255), stop:1 rgba(34, 34, 46, 255))")
        self.frame_main.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_main.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_main.setObjectName("frame_main")
        self.main_check = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_main)
        self.main_check.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 691, 70))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("URW Gothic [UKWN]")
        font.setPointSize(36)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.main_check.setFont(font)
        self.main_check.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);\n""color: white;")
        self.main_check.setObjectName("main_check")
        self.inp_check = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_check)
        self.inp_check.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(75, 300, 600, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("URW Gothic [urw]")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.inp_check.setFont(font)
        self.inp_check.setStyleSheet("background-color: #22222e;\n""border: 2px solid rgb(125, 200, 167);\n""border-radius: 30;\n""color: white;\n""padding-left:10px;\n""padding-right: 10px;")
        self.inp_check.setText("")
        self.inp_check.setClearButtonEnabled(False)
        self.inp_check.setObjectName("inp_check")
        self.but_check = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_check)
        self.but_check.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(225, 380, 300, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("URW Gothic [urw]")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.but_check.setFont(font)
        self.but_check.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n""    color: white;\n""    background-color:  rgb(125, 200, 167);\n""    border-radius: 30;\n""    outline: 0;\n""}\n""\n""QPushButton:pressed  {\n""    \n""    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n""    color: rgb(125, 200, 167);\n""    outline: 0;\n""}")
        self.but_check.setObjectName("but_check")
        self.lab_check = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_check)
        self.lab_check.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(75, 250, 591, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("URW Gothic [urw]")
        font.setPointSize(22)
        self.lab_check.setFont(font)
        self.lab_check.setStyleSheet("color: white;")
        self.lab_check.setObjectName("lab_check")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_check, "")
        self.tab_make = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_make.setObjectName("tab_make")
        self.frame_make = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.tab_make)
        self.frame_make.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 750, 150))
        self.frame_make.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(125, 200, 167, 255), stop:1 rgba(34, 34, 46, 255))")
        self.frame_make.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_make.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_make.setObjectName("frame_make")
        self.main_make = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_make)
        self.main_make.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 661, 70))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("URW Gothic [UKWN]")
        font.setPointSize(36)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.main_make.setFont(font)
        self.main_make.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);\n""color: white;")
        self.main_make.setObjectName("main_make")
        self.lab_make = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_make)
        self.lab_make.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(75, 250, 600, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("URW Gothic [urw]")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.lab_make.setFont(font)
        self.lab_make.setStyleSheet("border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(125, 200, 167);\n""padding-bottom: 0;\n""margin: 0;\n""color: white;")
        self.lab_make.setObjectName("lab_make")
        self.but_make = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_make)
        self.but_make.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 300, 250, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("URW Gothic [urw]")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.but_make.setFont(font)
        self.but_make.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n""    color: white;\n""    background-color:  rgb(125, 200, 167);\n""    border-radius: 25;\n""    outline: 0;\n""}\n""\n""QPushButton:pressed  {\n""    \n""    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n""    color: rgb(125, 200, 167);\n""    outline: 0;\n""}")
        self.but_make.setObjectName("but_make")
        self.frame_save_make = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.tab_make)
        self.frame_save_make.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 470, 360, 121))
        self.frame_save_make.setStyleSheet("\n""QFrame{\n""    border: 2px solid rgb(125, 200, 167);\n""    border-radius: 30;\n""}")
        self.frame_save_make.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_save_make.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_save_make.setObjectName("frame_save_make")
        self.radio_save_make = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.frame_save_make)
        self.radio_save_make.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 320, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("URW Gothic [urw]")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.radio_save_make.setFont(font)
        self.radio_save_make.setStyleSheet("QRadioButton{\n""    color: white;\n""    background-color:  rgb(125, 200, 167);\n""    border-radius: 25;\n""    outline: 0;\n""    padding-left: 30px;\n""}\n""QRadioButton::indicator{\n""    height: 0;\n""    width: 0;\n""}\n""QRadioButton::checked{\n""    color: rgb(125, 200, 167);\n""    background-color: white;\n""}    \n""")
        self.radio_save_make.setObjectName("radio_save_make")
        self.lab_umolch = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_save_make)
        self.lab_umolch.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(25, 80, 312, 22))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("URW Gothic L")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setItalic(True)
        self.lab_umolch.setFont(font)
        self.lab_umolch.setStyleSheet("color: white;\n""border:none\n""")
        self.lab_umolch.setObjectName("lab_umolch")
        self.frame_prim_make = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.tab_make)
        self.frame_prim_make.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 470, 360, 121))
        self.frame_prim_make.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid rgb(125, 200, 167);\n""border-radius: 30; color: white;")
        self.frame_prim_make.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_prim_make.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_prim_make.setObjectName("frame_prim_make")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_prim_make)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 321, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("URW Gothic L")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("border:none;")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.primech_inp_make = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame_prim_make)
        self.primech_inp_make.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 341, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("URW Gothic [urw]")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setItalic(True)
        self.primech_inp_make.setFont(font)
        self.primech_inp_make.setStyleSheet("border:2px solid rgb(125, 200, 167);;\n""border-radius: 20;\n""color: white;\n""padding-left: 7px;\n""padding-right: 7px;")
        self.primech_inp_make.setText("")
        self.primech_inp_make.setObjectName("primech_inp_make")
        self.dop_lab_make = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_make)
        self.dop_lab_make.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 430, 551, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("URW Gothic [UKWN]")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.dop_lab_make.setStyleSheet("color: white")
        self.dop_lab_make.setFont(font)
        self.dop_lab_make.setObjectName("dop_lab_make")
        self.frame_save_make.raise_()
        self.frame_make.raise_()
        self.main_make.raise_()
        self.lab_make.raise_()
        self.but_make.raise_()
        self.frame_prim_make.raise_()
        self.dop_lab_make.raise_()
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_make, "")
        self.tab_opt = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_opt.setObjectName("tab_opt")
        self.frame_opt = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.tab_opt)
        self.frame_opt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 750, 150))
        self.frame_opt.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(125, 200, 167, 255), stop:1 rgba(34, 34, 46, 255))")
        self.frame_opt.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_opt.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_opt.setObjectName("frame_opt")
        self.main_opt = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_opt)
        self.main_opt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 320, 70))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("URW Gothic [UKWN]") 
        font.setPointSize(36)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.main_opt.setFont(font)
        self.main_opt.setStyleSheet("color: white;\n""background-color: none;")
        self.main_opt.setObjectName("main_opt")
        self.frame_lang = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.tab_opt)
        self.frame_lang.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 520, 280, 60))
        self.frame_lang.setStyleSheet("QFrame{\n""    background-color: rgb(34, 34, 46);\n""    border: 2px solid rgb(125, 200, 167);\n""    border-radius: 30;\n""}\n""QLabel{\n""    border: none\n""}")
        self.frame_lang.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_lang.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_lang.setObjectName("frame_lang")
        self.lang = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.frame_lang)
        self.lang.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(205, 10, 50, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("URW Gothic [urw]")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.lang.setFont(font)
        self.lang.setStyleSheet("QComboBox{\n""    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);\n""    border: 2px solid rgb(125, 200, 167);\n""    border-radius: 4;\n""    color: white;\n""}\n""QComboBox::drop-down{\n""    width:0px;\n""    :0px;\n""    border: 0px;\n""}\n""QComboBox QAbstractItemView{\n""    color: rgb(125, 200, 167);\n""    padding: 10p;\n""    selection-background-color: rgb(143, 230, 191);\n""    background-color: rgb(34, 34, 46);\n""    border: 2px solid rgb(125, 200, 167);\n""    border-radius: 5;\n""}")
        self.lang.setObjectName("lang")
        self.lang.addItem("")
        self.lang.addItem("")
        self.lab_lang = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_lang)
        self.lab_lang.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 180, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("URW Gothic [UKWN]")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.lab_lang.setFont(font)
        self.lab_lang.setStyleSheet("color: white;")
        self.lab_lang.setObjectName("lab_lang")
        self.but_path_opt = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_opt)
        self.but_path_opt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 245, 250, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("URW Gothic [urw]")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.but_path_opt.setFont(font)
        self.but_path_opt.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n""    color: white;\n""    background-color:  rgb(125, 200, 167);\n""    border-radius: 25;\n""    outline: 0;\n""}\n""\n""QPushButton:pressed  { \n""      margin: 0;    \n""      padding: 40px;\n""\n""    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n""    color: rgb(125, 200, 167);\n""    outline: 0;\n""}")
        self.but_path_opt.setObjectName("but_path_opt")
        self.lab_where_save_opt = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_opt)
        self.lab_where_save_opt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 210, 661, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("URW Gothic [urw]")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.lab_where_save_opt.setFont(font)
        self.lab_where_save_opt.setStyleSheet("color: white;")
        self.lab_where_save_opt.setObjectName("lab_where_save_opt")
        self.radio_hiden_opt = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.tab_opt)
        self.radio_hiden_opt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 245, 250, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("URW Gothic [urw]")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.radio_hiden_opt.setFont(font)
        self.radio_hiden_opt.setStyleSheet("QRadioButton{\n""    background-color: rgb(125, 200, 167);\n""    border-radius:25;\n""    color: white;\n""    outline: 0;\n""    padding-left: 50px;\n""}\n""QRadioButton::indicator{\n""    height: 0;\n""    width: 0;\n""}\n""QRadioButton::checked{\n""    color: rgb(125, 200, 167);\n""    background-color: white;\n""}")
        self.radio_hiden_opt.setObjectName("radio_hiden_opt")
        self.frame_path = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.tab_opt)
        self.frame_path.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 200, 720, 201))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("URW Gothic [urw]")
        self.frame_path.setFont(font)
        self.frame_path.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid rgb(125, 200, 167);\n""border-radius: 30;")
        self.frame_path.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_path.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_path.setObjectName("frame_path")
        self.lab_name_opt = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_path)
        self.lab_name_opt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 110, 611, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("URW Gothic L")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.lab_name_opt.setFont(font)
        self.lab_name_opt.setStyleSheet("border: 0px solid rgba(0,0,0,0) ;\n""color: white;")
        self.lab_name_opt.setObjectName("lab_name_opt")
        self.set_name_opt = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame_path)
        self.set_name_opt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 137, 521, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("URW Gothic [urw]")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setItalic(True)
        self.set_name_opt.setFont(font)
        self.set_name_opt.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 20;\n""color: white;\n""padding-left: 5px;")
        self.set_name_opt.setObjectName("set_name_opt")
        self.frame_path.raise_()
        self.frame_lang.raise_()
        self.frame_opt.raise_()
        self.but_path_opt.raise_()
        self.lab_where_save_opt.raise_()
        self.radio_hiden_opt.raise_()
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_opt, "")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.download_folder = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'))
        self.lang.currentTextChanged.connect(lambda: self.retranslateUi(MainWindow))
        self.but_check.clicked.connect(self.pas_check)
        self.but_path_opt.clicked.connect(self.get_folder)
        self.but_make.clicked.connect(self.create)
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134092/discussion-on-question-by-alex-alexeev---py-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это баг на пересечении двух проектов: гномовской [glib](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib) и FDO'шного [shared-mime-info](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/shared-mime-info):

- в shared-mime-info [задали](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/shared-mime-info/-/blob/7bdcf3b6457979e9e928489ac6977b8ccc5880de/data/freedesktop.org.xml.in#L2022) слишком широкое значение для своих магических констант автоопределения типа файла, которое даёт ложноположительные срабатывания.
- glib [неверно](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/shared-mime-info-spec/shared-mime-info-spec-0.21.html) [использует](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/blob/6ee71750a532d8de5eaed5cf12e8718738ddd5c6/gio/gcontenttype.c#L840) аттрибут `priority` из базы данных mime, полагая, что высокий приоритет означает, уверенность в том, что файл относится к определённому типу.

Минимальный файл для воспроизведения, являющийся корректным питоновским скриптом:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore

# {
```

#### Что делать

Написать баг и тем и другим, чтоб исправили:

- в `glib` попросить, чтобы догадки с высоким приоритетом не перекрывали тот тип, который определён по расширению файла.
- в `shared-mime-info` попросить попытатся поправить свой угадыватель типа, или хотя бы уменьшить приоритет конкретно для этой записи, дабы сделать glib счастливым. Можно просто написать в старое обсуждение [тут](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/shared-mime-info/-/issues/84).

Надо быть готовым к тому, что ответят не сразу/будут задавать дополнительные вопросы

#### Что можно сделать прямо сейчас

Уменьшить приоритет на своей машине, т.е. в `/usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml` найти запись:

```
 <mime-type type="text/x-qml">
    <!-- ... -->
    <magic priority="80">
    <!-- ... -->
      <match type="string" value="import Qt" offset="0:3000">
        <match type="string" value="{" offset="9:3009"/>
      </match>
    <!-- ... -->
    </magic>
 </mime-type>
```

и заменить `80` на что-либо меньше, например, на `79`

А потом выполнить

```
update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

При обновлении пакета `shared-mime-info` эти изменения будут потеряны.

Comment: Можно ли прямо сейчас сделать так чтобы он задавал тип только по расширению файла?

Comment: @Alexalexeev вообще «только по расширению и всегда» разумными средствами — нельзя… только изменить поведение в glib (пропатчив её и пересобрав)… чтобы решить конкретно эту проблемы см. под заголовком «Что можно сделать прямо сейчас»

Comment: а если изменить в freedesktop.org.xml все на ноль?(возможно очень тупая идея)

Comment: как им можно об этом написать?

Comment: @Alexalexeev, см. [Reporting bugs в README](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/blob/main/README.md#user-content-reporting-bugs) … если кратко, то просто создать проблемы в [issues](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/issues) и указать всё что нужно… можешь также сослаться а FDO'шную спеку, что приоритеты больше 80 не обладают какой-то исключительностью…

Comment: @Alexalexeev, это не особо хорошая идея… можно изменить все значения на `<80`, тогда классификация на основе содержимого не будет перебивать то что получено на основе расширения… но сабтипизация на основе содержимого всё равно будет происходить… но это только замазывания бага в glib…

Comment: спасибо за то что помогли и объяснили :)

Comment: I think the fix is actually this: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/shared-mime-info/-/merge_requests/177